# Mariadb 10.4 in Kubernetes entrypoint.sh fails on temp server

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, mariadb

During the temp server startup on MariaDB 10.4 I intermittently get an error that the server can't start on port 0. This is when my user would be created and granted privileges. I've looked around and found mention of MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD but setting this to false did not make a difference. Is this

```
Log Message:
2020-02-14 13:46:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2020-02-14 13:46:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2020-02-14 13:46:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
2020-02-14 13:46:48 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic) starting as process 124 ...
2020-02-14 13:46:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-02-14 13:46:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-02-14 13:46:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-02-14 13:46:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-02-14 13:46:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-02-14 13:46:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-02-14 13:46:48 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2020-02-14 13:46:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-02-14 13:46:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-02-14 13:46:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-02-14 13:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-02-14 13:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-02-14 13:46:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.12 started; log sequence number 61100; transaction id 21
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200214 13:47:18
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@mysql-7f6d9d7686-bjdcx' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Warning] 'user' entry '@mysql-7f6d9d7686-bjdcx' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@mysql-7f6d9d7686-bjdcx' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-02-14 13:47:18 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic' socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 0 mariadb.org binary distribution
2020-02-14 13:47:19+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Unable to start server.



Kubernetes Config:
####This file creates both the deployment and service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "3306"
    port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mysql
  name: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: ********
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: ********
        - name: MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "yes"
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: ********
        image: mariadb:10.4
        name: mysql
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "2048Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          name: ********
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: ********
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: ********
status: {}
'''
```

Comment: Please include in your post the log file where you see the error with "MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD". Your mount volume is empty, or there are some content ?

Comment: Yes the volume mount is empty when starting.

Comment: Are you using some entrypoint to apply some database settings? I'ves tested your deployment here and it's ok for me.

Comment: I am using the standard entrypoint that comes with mariadb. I have made no changes to the image. The error occurs intermittently so I was wondering if it was possibly a resource issue but that doesn't seem likely since pod has no problem being scheduled. The next time I restart the pod and clear the PVC I will hopefully be able to get an example of the error with the MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD set to false.

Comment: Ok I'm waiting for the logs. Additionally you could check your storage connections, if it was under the network like NFS or similar maybe some network issue is interfering. As I said before, your deployment file works for me.